# Login doesn't "stick"

Tags: users

I have been working on website with drupal 7.
The website went live at 8/2016, I've noticed recently that I keep getting logged out from the site and have to log in regularly when browsing.
The problem has start with me at 21/12/2016.
I read related questions, all the answers were talking about :

1. http/https conflict , I made sure that the site is only http version
2. www/ !www , I made sure that all the www versions will be directed to !www version
3. cookie problem , I have tried that on different browsers, and the problem was the same.
4. timing issue : The server team has turn off the firewall and reset the time and server, but nothing happened
5. session table size: I have cleared all the record in the session table, then tried again !
6. caching issue: I didn't use any caching module, it's drupal core caching and it's not enabled
7. module updates : I haven't update any module since the website went live, and it was working properly for 3 months
8. session expiration, the server team put these values to unlimited!
9. php upgrading issue: there wasn't any upgrade on the server.

All the solution above didn't work for me. Can you advice please with any suggestion ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [users are getting logged out after they login](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/224912/users-are-getting-logged-out-after-they-login)

Comment: yes, I was trying to edit it , I will remove the oldest one.

Comment: I have tried the solutions in the comment, but no result ! @Kevin

Comment: `cookie problem , I have tried that on different browsers, and the problem was the same.` What is often meant with login cookie problems is the `$cookie_domain = '.example.com';` option in your `settings.php` file. And while in the settings, also check `ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 200000);` and `ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 2000000);`. Finally `session expiration, the server team put these values to unlimited!` That does not exist... It is always a number of seconds. If they did set it to 0, you need to login every time you close the browser.

Comment: Also have a look here: https://www.drupal.org/project/session_expire. It explains a problem and provides a solution.

Comment: Hi @Neograph734,
I have checked the values in settings.php
They seem to be right :
1- $cookie_domain: is set to the right domain with (.).
2- session settings they are : 200000, 20000000
3- session expiration module: I have used it, but no change !

Comment: Hi @Neograph734 I have found the problem
The problem of logging out was happening in certain pages,
Those pages were generated by the same view.
After many searches : 
the main problem was one line 
$_SESSION['view'] = $view
which was inside a hook for this view.

Comment: Nice, glad you solved this.